# Excluding project configuration files from commits in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I have a project that requires some configuration files. I want to keep the default configuration filse in the repository. However, I want don't want to have to specify the -X flag for every commit I do. Is there a standard way to mark a set of revisioned files as permanently excluded from commits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question, I hope you get a better answer.  Faced similar problems, I have done the following:

- Rename the configuration files, so that for example, instead of `noweb.cfg` I have `noweb.cfg.default`.  This file changes seldom and is kept under revision control.
- The actual configuration file, `noweb.cfg`, may change frequently but is put in the `.hgignore` file so it is never committed.
- At need I have a special Makefile target that rebuilds `*.cfg` from `*.cfg.default`.

This solution is not ideal because changes in the `.cfg` files are lost when the `.cfg.default` changes.  In principle you could tackle this issue with diff3 or some more sophisticated merge tool, but I have never been energetic enough to go there.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the (much maligned) defaults section in your .hgrc:

```
  [defaults]
  commit = -X thefileyouwanttoexclude
```

If you can retrain your fingers the preferred way to do that is with an alias instead:

```
 [alias]
  cmt = commit -X thefileyouwanttoexclude
```

then you start using `hg cmt` instead of commit.

Comment: Why do you say "much maligned"? Is it frowned upon? Or just not well known?

Comment: It works fine, but mpm, mercurial's creator, has deprecated [defaults].  It, by design, alters what commands do in invisible ways,  so scripts or extensions that use those commands are running the commands with arguments they might not intend.

For example, if I do "[defaults]\npush = -f" because I always want to use -f that's fine, but if a script uses 'push' without -f because it wants to make sure not to create new remote heads, that script would be using -f w/o knowing it.  Aliases are just safer and accomplish almost the same thing, provided one can retrain one's fingers.